# PowerBI IF value IN TOPN values then TRUE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here. But I'm having no luck.

What I'd like to do is to create a new `TRUE`/`FALSE` column based upon a value within a column being in the top 2 results of the same column.

This snippet currently works for the "Max Value"

```
isCurrent =
IF (
    'Program'[MajorVersion] = MAXX ( 'Program', 'Program'[MajorVersion] ),
    TRUE (),
    FALSE ()
)
```

What I'd prefer working is not just the `MAXX` value but the top 2 values within that column. So I am using the `TOPN` function below. Unfortunately, this is not working.

```
isCurrent =
IF (
    'Program'[MajorVersion]
        IN TOPN (
            2,
            FILTER ( 'Program', 'Program'[MajorVersion] ),
            'Program'[MajorVersion], DESC
        ),
    TRUE (),
    FALSE ()
)
```

Table example:

```
ID  MajorVersion
1       18.4
2       18.4
3       18.5
4       18.2
5       18.6
6       18.6
7       18.4
8       18.4
9       18.6
10      18.6
```

Desired Result: (Since the top 2 values within MajorVersion would be 18.5 & 18.6)

```
ID  MajorVersion  isCurrent
1       18.4       FALSE
2       18.4       FALSE
3       18.5       TRUE
4       18.2       FALSE
5       18.6       TRUE
6       18.6       TRUE
7       18.4       FALSE
8       18.4       FALSE
9       18.6       TRUE
10      18.6       TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with the way you're trying to do it.

First, `TOPN` returns the top `N` rows, not the top `N` values in a column.

Second, `TOPN` returns full rows, not just a single column.

To fix both of these, you can do a `TOPN` on `VALUES(Program[MajorVersion])`:

```
isCurrent =
Program[MajorVersion] IN
    TOPN(2,
        VALUES(Program[MajorVersion]),
        Program[MajorVersion],
        DESC
    )
```

This already returns `True` or `False` without needing the `IF`.

Comment: Hi Alexis, Thank you very much for such a quick response. I had wrongfully assumed that since I filtered the table i would only be looking at the 2 rows of the one column. It definitely makes a lot more sense now that I'm looking at what you did. Thanks again and have a great weekend.